# How to prevent my web proxy site to be report as a fishing site

Tags: security, web, seo

I have a web proxy site to help chinese, they can view a webpage blocked by government by a modified url, like http://www.google.com.mywebproxy.domain/.

But some website has been report as a fishing site on google and others. I need know the rules how search engine detect a fishing site, and I can block some page that I should never proxy.

for example, how can I detect a website has a form input credit card information?

Comment: No filtering site is going to provide an explicit list of their algorithm. If there were a simple "do this and you won't be blocked," then fishers would do that. But if filtering sites (including google) are marking you incorrectly, you should talk to them about it. Every filtering site wants to be accurate.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks, reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I detect a website has a form input credit card information?

I know it somewhat simplistic, but what about a simple rule that looks for Credit Card related terms on page/in form?

Think about it, for phishing attack to work, the attacker will need to convince the visitor - in one way or another - to provide his/hers CC info. So you can make a list of payment related terms like "credit card, payment, CC, billing" and so on and use them to determent page intent.

Having said that:

a: images/flash will provide a loophole

b: you`ll need to cover different translations of all terms

c: as in your case, some "legit" sites will be blocked

This of course dose not describe the working of Google (or other) filtering algorithms which use a more complex set of rules based on multiple verification vectors and existing data pools for cross-reference.

An exact mix of those is a closely guarded secret and I agree with Rob, contacting someone for a manual check-up is probably the best solution.